# Can Apache configuration check cookies?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, mobile

My situation:

We have a mobile version of our website, and want to start redirecting mobile users to it. The plan is to do this in Apache `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`, using something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iPhone|Blackberry|...)
RewriteRule (.*) mobile/$1
```

However we want there to be a way for users to override our default action of redirecting them. One way we thought to do it was to show a link on the mobile site directing back to the regular site, and store a cookie when they use that link.

Could the Apache configuration file check a cookie before redirecting?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

The `HTTP_COOKIE` server variable contains the cookies passed from the client to the server. You can look in there to find out what cookies have been generated by a script or module.